Eagon-Northcott complex
I'm reading Eisenbud's geometry of syzygies about the Eagon-Northcott complex. He states that one can show that this is a complex by inductive construction as a mapping cone. However, from the definition in the book, it's not clear to me that the Eagon-Northcott complex is a mapping cone. Can anyone points me to a source that works this out?
